# Regex printable ascii plus newline and carriage return

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a validator function in javascript for data entry.  I have two conditions I need to test for.

Case 1:  All printable ASCII characters between 32 and 126
Case 2:  All printable ASCII characters between 32 and 126 plus carriage return and new line.

Here is my regex for Case 1:

```
/^(?=[ -~])[^\r\n]*$/
```

Is this suitable for Case 2?

```
/^(?=[\n-~])[^\013\014\016-\037]*$/
```

Comment: 1) You just need `^[ -~]*$`, the CR and LF are out of this range. 2) `^[ -~\r\n]*$` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

1. `^[ -~]*$`, this pattern matches any printable ASCII chars *without* carriage return and a line feed chars because they are simply out of this range.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ORmbRC/1).

2. `^[ -~\r\n]*$` will do because  `-~` defines the range described above + a line feed and a carriage return.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ORmbRC/2).

Also, check the [ASCII table codes](https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/references/ascii-table) to see what is included in the ranges above.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `\r` (return carriage) in the second one

```
/^(?=[\n\r-~])[^\013\014\016-\037]*$/
```

Comment: The `[\n\r-~]` allows some unprintable chars because of the unescape `-`, and if you escape it, it will still not work as expected because it will only match LF, CR, `-` or `~`